# Написание слова «Рождество»

Tags: орфография, стилистика, прописная-строчная

Возник такой вопрос: а нужно ли писать «Рождество» с большой буквы (не только тогда, когда поздравляешь, но и в целом) всегда?
Возьмем, допустим, книги. Правильно ли, что слово «Рождество», встречающееся там, будет написано всегда с большой буквы? Или это непринципиально? На разных сайтах по этому вопросу рассматриваются только случаи поздравлений. Так как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, конечно же, не всегда. "Почти всегда" - вот с этим я бы согласился...

Рождество с заглавной пишется (да и то - с оговорками), только когда речь идет о празднике. Если о самом событии (что редкость), то заглавная возможна в особом, торжественно-патетическом стиле и/или по церковным рекомендациям - но по этим правилам вообще все, что даже отдаленно относится к теме Христа, требует заглавной. Но в гражданском правописании такого жесткого требования нет.

Вот вам пример (не из частых, конечно) иронического использования слова, где заглавная просто неуместна.

> «На еврейское рождество да на турецкую пасху», ― говаривала в детстве
>   наша соседка тетя Катя, когда желала подчеркнуть невероятность
>   какого-то события.

Михаэль Дорфман. "Еврейское Рождество"

Самое смешное, что название самого произведения дано с заглавной, что отражает явную путаницу в головах редакторов-корректоров.

К сожалению, вы не привели ни одного примера, поэтому рассуждать приходится несколько умозрительно.

Answer (score 0):

Мы говорим о Рождестве Христовом (полностью: Рождество Господа Бога и Спасителя нашего Иисуса Христа), и необходимо писать с большой буквы, даже если из двух слов, что бывает, оставляем только первое. Это одно из важных событий для человечества и церковное празднество.